# How to get the name of a tenant/Azure AD from an application in azure, using REST API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, rest

I am writing an application that uses application tokens against Azure AD for authentication. So, I have the tenant ID, Client ID & Client secret with me to work with. Is there any REST API I can use to get the Azure AD/Tenant name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is the Get organization endpoint in MS Graph API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization
```

Example response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 411

{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#organization",
  "value": [
    {
      "assignedPlans": [
        {
          "assignedDateTime": "datetime-value",
          "capabilityStatus": "capabilityStatus-value",
          "service": "service-value",
          "servicePlanId": "servicePlanId-value"
        }
      ],
      "businessPhones": [
        "businessPhones-value"
      ],
      "city": "city-value",
      "country": "country-value",
      "countryLetterCode": "countryLetterCode-value",
      "displayName": "displayName-value"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you are calling this endpoint as an application (not on behalf of a user), you need one of the following app permissions:

- Organization.Read.All
- Directory.Read.All
- Organization.ReadWrite.All
- Directory.ReadWrite.All